# How to replace all values (all NAs) in a column with numeric part of the file name?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, command-line, bioinformatics

I have multiple (22) files that are named like this:

chr1.out, chr2.out...,chr22.out

each of those files has 46 columns and multiple lines

The first 6 columns and 6 rows in one of those files looks like this:

```
  alternate_ids      rsid chromosome position alleleA alleleB index
     rs4814683 rs4814683         NA     9795       G       T     1
     rs6076506 rs6076506         NA    11231       T       G     2
     rs6139074 rs6139074         NA    11244       A       C     3
     rs1418258 rs1418258         NA    11799       C       T     4
     rs7274499 rs7274499         NA    12150       C       A     5
     rs6116610 rs6116610         NA    12934       G       A     6
```

Let's say this is in file chr1.out

what I would like to do is to replace all NAs in column chromosome with 1.

so it would look like this:

```
  alternate_ids      rsid chromosome position alleleA alleleB index
     rs4814683 rs4814683         1     9795       G       T     1
     rs6076506 rs6076506         1    11231       T       G     2
     rs6139074 rs6139074         1    11244       A       C     3
     rs1418258 rs1418258         1    11799       C       T     4
     rs7274499 rs7274499         1    12150       C       A     5
     rs6116610 rs6116610         1    12934       G       A     6
```

I would like to do the same for each of those 22 files. So chr2.out get 2 in 3rd column, chr3.out get's 3 in 3rd column etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp_d=$(mktemp -q -d -t 'replace.XXXXX' || mktemp -q -d)

for f in chr*.out; do
    tmp_f="${tmp_d}/$f"
    n="${f#chr}"
    n="${n%.out}"
    awk -v n="$n" '$3 == "NA" { $3=n }1' "$f" > "$tmp_f"
    mv "$tmp_f" "$f"
done

rm -r "$tmp_d"
```

First we make a tmp directory as we will be creating tmp files

Then we loop through each `chr*.out` file.

- Create a variable for this file in the tmp directory
- remove the `chr` prefix
- remove the `.out` suffix
- `awk` will then replace any `NA` in the third column with the number extracted from the filename and save that to the tmp file
- replace the original file with the tmp file

After the loop finishes we remove the tmp directory.

*all the tmp stuff can be avoided if you have GAWK which can use the `-i` in place option*

Comment: would it be cleaner to do `for n in {1..22}` and generate the filename around `n`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Maybe but I wanted to make it somewhat reusable on different sets of files.  Although I'm not sure how necessary that would be.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one `sed` script to handle all files.

```
sed -i 's/         NA  /          1  /' chr{1..22}.out
```